# Instancing XMLStreamWriterFactory failed: unsupported property isRepairingNamespaces

Tags: java, jax-ws, classloader, xmlstreamwriter

In our application we encounter very sporadic run time exceptions which crash our message processors (which are stand-alone java processes running on Java 8). The processors, at the time of this exception, generally try to execute a web service call.

The exception are

```
java.lang.Error: Failed to create new instance of com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamWriterFactory$1
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.streaming.ContextClassloaderLocal.createNewInstance(ContextClassloaderLocal.java:63)
  ..
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to access unsupported property javax.xml.stream.isRepairingNamespaces
  at weblogic.xml.stax.ConfigurationContextBase.check(ConfigurationContextBase.java:90)
```

The strange thing is, the whole application is *running without errors 99.9% of the time*: the above exceptions happen quite infrequently (ca. every couple of days). After a crash, the processors are restarted automatically, and again operate perfectly fine, until the same exception occurs again after a seemingly random interval.

So far we could not correlate this with any misbehavior on the part of the JVM or the host the application is running on.

**Does anyone have any pointers as to why such an `unsupported property javax.xml.stream.isRepairingNamespaces` exception could appear sporadically?**

We're running `jdk1.8.0_66` on `Red Hat 4.8.5-4`. Web service interfaces are generated using `JAX-WS`.

---

Edit:
I can't share the classpath (lots of internal info, sorry). We do have the Weblogic full client in there though: `wlfullclient-12.1.3.jar`. It defines an XML factory via ServiceLoader

```
META-INF/services/javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory --> weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLOutputFactory
```

Where as `xml-apis-1.4.01.jar` (also on classpath) contains javax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory.class (related to the exception thrown in ConfigurationContextBase).

Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: The context class loader failed to create a new object instance of a class. Can you share the classpath of the application? Is an alternate version of JAX-WS RI (jaxws-rt-<version>.jar) in the classpath?

Comment: I can't share the class path sorry, but I updated my question. Please let me know if I should add more info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the class path order. At first point all the `axis2 jars` and then point the `weblogic.jar` in class path. Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: The strange part is that the application works 99% of the time. It's not that it fails every time...

Comment: Do you have implemented recommended format ? @fgysin

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do you mean by 'implemented recommended format'?

Comment: @fgysin are you using eclipse? If yes, then which version? Could you please check in Mars and Luna version.

Comment: We are using Eclipse, but not for building and packaging (done via maven).

Comment: @fgysin I mean if you use Apache axis2, then you must have to keep `axis2 jars` first in classpath and then your `weblogic jar`.

Comment: I'll give this a try

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem yesterday after making some significant changes to my code. This particular post is the ONLY information I can find by googling this particular error -- always a bad sign. After hours and hours of fruitless deep debugging, comparing the original working version of the code with the new non-working version, I decided to start backing out my code changes to see where/when the problem originated. Well, after backing out pretty much every single code change, the problem was still happening. I finally realized that this problem was perhaps external to the code. It turns out that at some point, I had added an extraneous library: wstx.jar to my lib directory. Once I removed that lib, everything worked great. So apparently it was utilizing the wrong classes to try to perform this operation.

Not sure if that is of any assistance to you, but even if not, I thought someone someday might stumble onto this and find it to be useful.

Comment: I have moved on to new projects and can't validate this, but appreciate the late input. Thanks!